# AVG(MAX()) doesnot work in CASE statement , ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case, aggregate-functions

Hello I am practicing in oracle's hr schema . I want to count avarage of maximum salaries grouped by countries and jobs.
when I use 
        `avg(max(e.salary))`
in case expression it returns `not a single-group group function` error

```
`select c.country_id AS "COUNTRY CODE",
   e.job_id AS "JOB",
   case 
      when max(e.salary)>avg(max(e.salary)) then 'HIGH SALARY'
      else 'LOW SALARY'
   end as info
   from
   hr.employees e right join hr.departments d on 
    e.department_id=d.department_id
           right join hr.locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
           right join hr.countries c on l.country_id=c.country_id
    group by c.country_id,e.job_id;`
```

but when I select it seperately it works fine :

```
`select  avg(max(e.salary)) as "AVARAGE"
 from hr.employees e right join hr.departments d on 
 e.department_id=d.department_id
           right join hr.locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
           right join hr.countries c on l.country_id=c.country_id
 group by c.country_id,e.job_id;`
```

can you explain me how to use `avg(max())` functions together in case statement? thank you in advance.

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_.

Answer (score 2):

One quick fix here might be to try using `AVG()` as an analytic function, over the entire aggregated table:

```
select
    c.country_id AS "COUNTRY CODE",
    e.job_id AS "JOB",
    case 
        when max(e.salary) > avg(max(e.salary)) over ()
        then 'HIGH SALARY'
        else 'LOW SALARY'
    end as info
from hr.employees e
right join hr.departments d
    on e.department_id = d.department_id
right join hr.locations l
    on d.location_id = l.location_id
right join hr.countries c
    on l.country_id = c.country_id
group by
    c.country_id,
    e.job_id;
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but is it possible to achieve these results without analytic function? above solutions gave me wrong results

Comment: The thing is, knowing what the _average_ max value is in your `GROUP BY` query requires, by definition, iterating that entire result set once to find the average.  So, if you don't use `AVG() OVER()` you would have to subquery and find the average that way.

Comment: `select t.country_id as COUNTRY_CODE, t.job_id as JOB, case 
      when t.max_salary > avg(t.max_salary) then 'HIGH SALARY'
      else 'LOW SALARY'
   end as info 
from (select c.country_id,
       e.job_id,
       max(e.salary) as max_salary
       from
       hr.employees e right join hr.departments d on 
        e.department_id=d.department_id
               right join hr.locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
               right join hr.countries c on l.country_id=c.country_id
        group by c.country_id,e.job_id) t
group by t.country_id, t.job_id, t.max_salary;`

Comment: this returns "low salary" on every row which is not correct but I couldnot get what is wrong with this

Comment: I recommend my current answer, because the alternative would be substantially more code.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select t1.[COUNTRY_CODE], t1.JOB, case 
      when t1.salary > avg(t1.salary) then 'HIGH SALARY'
      else 'LOW SALARY'
   end as info 
from (select c.country_id AS "COUNTRY CODE",
       e.job_id AS "JOB",
       max(e.salary) as salary
       from
       hr.employees e right join hr.departments d on 
        e.department_id=d.department_id
               right join hr.locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
               right join hr.countries c on l.country_id=c.country_id
        group by c.country_id,e.job_id) as t1;
group by t1.[COUNTRY_CODE], t1.JOB, t1.salary
```

Comment: it returns "ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification" error

Comment: `[COUNTRY_CODE]` is an invalid identifier in SQL. You need to remove those square brackets. Plus: the column is named `country_id` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by one outer select and separate `max` and `avg` function like following:

```
With dataa as 
(select c.country_id,
       e.job_id,
       max(e.salary) as max_salary
       from
       hr.employees e right join hr.departments d on 
        e.department_id=d.department_id
               right join hr.locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id
               right join hr.countries c on l.country_id=c.country_id
        group by c.country_id,e.job_id)

select t.country_id as COUNTRY_CODE, t.job_id as JOB, case 
          when t.max_salary > t_avg.avg_salary then 'HIGH SALARY'
          else 'LOW SALARY'
       end as info 
    from dataa t,
 (select Avg(max_salary) as avg_salary from Dataa) t_avg;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I think it doesnot return correct answer, I got correct answer with solution of  Tim Biegelsein but I want to achieve it without analytic function

Comment: it returns 'LOW SALARY' for each row

Answer (score 0):

Nested aggravate function not allowed.
You should first get max salaries. Then again select on result with avg function.
Thanks,